# How to display tiles in my home page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to place some tiles in my Homepage, they are categories, user could click any of them to navigate to the proper page, and  if user click the tile longer, he could pin the tile as secondary tile to the phone page. The number of tiles may changed in the future, so I don't want to put fix number of rectangles in the xaml, anybody can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the HubTile control in the free [WP Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/). A guide can be found here: [Windows Phone HubTile in depth](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-hubtile-in-depth-part1-key-concepts-and-api)

I use these in some apps and they are great. They do not give you the functionality to pin to the Start screen though. But you should be able to simply use the same data to create a hub tile and a Start screen secondary tile at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to pay some bucks you could try the TreeMap control which is inside the [Syncfusion Essential Fusion for Windows Phone](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-phone/controls).

Comment: Is there away to implement it?

Comment: Or only let the tiles support reorder and delete from the page, not support pin to phone home page.